# react-native build, stuck in between

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-emulator

when running my project on android emulator

```
react-native run-android
```

build the project start and then stops on :

```
 Bundling `index.android.js`  [development, non-minified, hmr disabled]  ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░  0.0% (0/4)
```

i tried fixing it by `cleaning the project`, uninstalling watchman and other stuffs but its not working yet. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

When i get stuck like that I re-render a new project then I copy my project files to it. If that doesn't work start looking for an error in your code i guess !

Comment: i tried that once, but i when i start working with native base, and adding images it stucks again, i remove the code to the point it was working but it didnt work too, and keep on stucking

Comment: Sorry for the late response .. Any better now ? You should share some code where you place the images please